# setTimeout("window.close()", 100) not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, firefox

I am a learner on HTML, PHP, Javascript.

I am currently working on a barcode scanning system.  The steps are simple, scan in an order number, the system(form) will then generate another sequence number and print it out along with the scanned order number right away so that the warehouse worker can stick the print out on the scanned parcel.
Same steps keep on until the whole log of cargo done.

We have created a simplified program, and test it.  If it works then we can follow the same logic to create the actual form.

Up to this point, we have successfully scan in the bar code, the form then jump into another form by using windows.open.  Inside this pop up windows, it is a PDF document which's created by FPDF.  By enable FIREFOX silence print feature.  The pop up form can printout the label automatically.  Everything good except we cannot close the popup windows.  We have already drilled out every possibilities and search thru the net...couldn't find anything. 
We did turn on the Firefox option `dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows` to `TRUE`

**first form**

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$_SESSION['CUSTNO']=$_REQUEST['CUSTNO'];
$_SESSION['ORDERNO']=$_REQUEST['ORDERNO']   ;
//header('Location:TESTwai.php');
echo "myFunction();";
}
?>


<html>

<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="form1"><br>
<input type="text" id="CUSTNO" name="CUSTNO"  style="font-size: 24pt"/>
<input type="text" id="ORDERNO" name="ORDERNO"  style="font-size: 24pt"/>
<br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="return myFunction()"></form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    //window.open("ex.php","", "width=200, height=100");
    window.open("ex.php","", "width=1000, height=1000");

    myWindow.close();   // Closes the new window

}
</script>
```

---

**Second pop up window form**
I have put the `setTimeout`, `close.window` inside or out PHP script and still no luck.

```
<?php

require('pdf_js.php');


class PDF_AutoPrint extends PDF_JavaScript
{
function AutoPrint($dialog=false)
{

    //Open the print dialog or start printing immediately on the standard printer
    //$param=($dialog ? 'true' : 'false');
    //echo $param;
    //$script="print($param);";
    $script="print(false);";
    $this->IncludeJS($script);
}
}
$pdf=new PDF_AutoPrint();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',20);
$pdf->Text(90, 50, 'Print me!');
//Open the print dialog
$pdf->AutoPrint('false');
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output();

?>
<script>
setTimeout("window.close()", 100);
</script>
```

**Please ignore those customer, orderno**. They are just dummy input...

The actual testing is just 
1) press the submit button
2) pop up windows
3) auto print the label out without any system prompt
4) close the pop up windows and get back to the first form  (stuck here)

Comment: Have you set the headers in the popUp page?

Comment: you cannot close a page with javascript from within itself. all browser are moving toward this principle. (previously it was a common practice among the js developers)

Comment: So what is the best strategy to overcome this kind of situation? I know stealth printing is not a good practice for a web application.  But this application is mainly for internal operation...As I am a client-server programmer, stealth printing(like label printout without user interrupt after a bar code scanned) is common and also a most efficient way for a warehouse label printout of each individual inbound parcels.  Scan the bar code and print at the background silently without clicking the cross to close the windows.....

Answer (score 0):

It is not a issue with `setTimeout` method. This is the issue with `window.close()` . It is not a good practice to close the window within itself.
Still if you its very necessary you can try the below code:

```
window.open('','_parent',''); //fool the browser that it was opened with a script
window.close();
```

You can put this in a function and call it use in `setTimeout` .[Helpful link](http://www.yournewdesigner.com/css-experiments/javascript-window-close-firefox.html)

Comment: I have followed your suggestion and added a small function closewindow(according to your helpful link )into "pop up" windows(form 2).  It seems that the form doesn't take any javascript to execute.  I have also tried to echo a statement inside this php and still nothing coming from the pop up.  Am I doing anything wrong or this FPDF PDF pop up is not allow to windows close ?